# Escape a literal so that it is wrapped with double quotes

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm-postgres

We use doctrine 2 and want to write parameterised code like this:

```
attributes @> \'{' . $con->quote($attrId) . ':' . (int)$value . '}\'';
```

to have a query like this:

```
WHERE attributes @>'{"color":14}';
```

The `"color"` is the custom (user chosen) name of an attribute. So I feel that [`quote()`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#quote) is an appropriate function to shield it. But it wraps a parameter with single quotes, what makes the request syntax incorrect.

[`quoteIdentifier()`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#quoteidentifier) function wraps with double quotes, BUT I'm not sure if it's right to use it in this context.

**How to build a safe code to get the request I need?**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with `json_build_object` and `pg_exec_params`:

```
<?php
$dbconn = pg_connect('');
$data = 'some"th\'ing';
pg_query_params($dbconn, 'SELECT json_build_object($1::text, $2::integer)', [$data, 14]);
?>
```

You need the explicit type casts so that PostgreSQL knows whether the argument is a string or a number.

Comment: Thank you! But, do we really need pg_query_params() when json_build_object() kind of does the thing?

Comment: Just found in Postgres docs about similar function to_json(anyelement) "...For any scalar type other than a number, a Boolean, or a null value, the text representation will be used, properly quoted and escaped so that it is a valid JSON string."

Answer (score 0):

You can include the double quotes in the string.

```
$attr = '{"' . $attrId . '":' . (int) $value . '}';
```

Don't depend on quoting to keep you safe, but instead execute the query with a method that binds the value to a prepared statement.

```
$statement = $con->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE attributes @> ?', [$attr]);
```